# Best practice to upload file to cdn while developing mobile application?

Tags: android, azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage

I am making mobile application . I have used Azure mobile service as  the backend services for to build mobile application . In mobile app i have to upload images to azure cloud storage . I can do by two method .

1. Uploading file from the client application
2. uploding by sending byte array or base64 string of file to server
   and server will uplod that file to them

I think  first method is good as  it is directly going to upload file instead of  going to server and pushing again to azure storage .

I don't know which approch is good . Any help is appriciated

Comment: Your title asks about CDN but your question doesn't mention CDN at all. Also: It's unclear what you're referring to in item 1: Are you asking about your client app direct-connecting to, and uploading to, Azure Storage? Regardless: Asking which approach is "best" is an off-topic question as it's going to just get you opinions. And also this question, as it stands, is very broad. Before this question ends up being closed, please edit your question to be a specific programming question (and to clarify the question I raised).

Comment: @DavidMakogon , if you read question i have mention there azure cloud storage which is CDN :)

Answer (score 3):

As David mentioned, the question is a bit broad and not related to CDN, but within the scope of Azure Mobile Services, I would recommend option #1, as that offers a few benefits, including (but not limited to):

- Minimized load on your Mobile Service, potentially avoiding the need to scale the service to keep up with file management
- Ability to use the storage APIs designed to handle blob management from the client and avoid having to implement and maintain similar APIs as part of your service (including support to resume uploads/download and other nice features for mobile apps)
- Ability to (more easily) use the different geographic locations offered by Azure Storage to have clients upload and download files using the nearest location.

And the list goes on...

The recommendation is still to expose an API from your service to allow clients to request a SAS token in order to provide authenticated access to storage. This approach is similar to what is used by the Mobile Apps File Management SDK.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party service like Filestack that handles the uploading & storing files, and the CDN delivery.

You can upload files directly to Azure with the [pick and store method](https://filestack.com/docs/javascript-api/pick-and-store):

```
filepicker.pickAndStore(
  {
    mimetype:"image/*",
    multiple: true
  },
  {
    location:"azure"
  },
  function(Blobs){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Blobs));
  },
  function(error){
//  console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); - print errors to console
  },
  function(progress){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(progress));
  }
);
```

And then every file uploaded generates a CDN url that you can use to deliver the image in your application. Not sure if you've looked into what CDN you want to use yet, but Filestack partners with Fastly so you have all of their features, which is one of the best.

Answer (score -2):

I use Cloudinary is a image back-end for web or mobile development, It's really easy upload images to a CDN.

Comment: This is far from a "best practice" - this is a promotion of a 3rd-party service. And opinion-based. And doesn't answer the question.